# How to classify an undefined vector list item?

Tags: c#, list, structure

I understand that an undefined vector3 = default(vector3), but what about a vector list item that does not exist?  For example:

```
List<Vector3> stuff = new List<Vector3>();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
stuff.add(new Vector3(0 + i, 0, 0));
}
```

In this case what would stuff[15] be considered?  I know it is undefined, but lets say that you did not know if it's defined or not.  How would you find out if it was?  Like, if stuff[15] is undefined print("stuff[15] is undefined") and break.

Comment: Are you asking what happens if you try to access an index outside the bounds of the List?

Comment: Yes.  I know you get "Argment is out of range", but what do you call it?  Like if(stuff[15] == undefined){what would undefined be}

Comment: stuff[15] doesn't exist. It's an exception. Since you have not added 15 elements, but only 10, it can not access the 16 element, or at the 15th index

Comment: Is this a terminology question? If so, `stuff[15]` would be considered "undefined." I am not sure what more you want to know about it.

Comment: If you have a function that takes specific items from a list to either remove them or put them in another list, how do you prevent it from going outside the range of the list?  if stuff[15] is undefined then break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer partly thanks to Frontear's answer.

```
List<Vector3> stuff = new List<Vector3>();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
stuff.add(new Vector3(0 + i, 0, 0));
}

if(15 > stuff.Count ){
print("stuff[15] is undefined")
break;
}
```

So, all undefined list items are obviously out of the range of the number of defined list items and, therefore, to find out if a list item is undefined just compare it's number to the number of defined list items.

I suppose it was a very simple answer, I just thought there was a word that you could set the defined/undefined list item equal to to get a boolean value representing if it was defined or not; like stuff[15]==undefined.  Apparently not...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking if your code will be able to access `stuff[15]`, no.

The reason for this is because you only add 10 elements to it, each of type vector.

```
List<Vector3> stuff = new List<Vector3>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stuff.add(new Vector3(0 + i, 0, 0));
}
```

This code will add a new Vector 10 times with the positions given, where the first parameter is 0 + i. Since there are only 10 elements, stuff[15] will not be accessed, and will throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

To safely check if an array can contain a 15th element, use an if statement

```
if (stuff.Length > 15) {
    stuff[15]; // will only be called if an element exists
}
```